# Why PHP class does not return `<h1>404</h1><p>Not found</p>`?

Tags: php, string, class

Why PHP class does not return `<h1>404</h1><p>Not found</p>`?

```
class checkid{
    public $title;
    public $content;
    function status(){
        $this->title='404';
        $this->content='Not found';
    }
}
$checkid=new checkid($url);
//$id=0;
((isset($id)) ? '' : $checkid->status().$title=$checkid->title.$content=$checkid->content);
//Why it does not return `<h1>404</h1><p>Not found</p>`?
echo "<h1>$title</h1><p>$content</p>";
```

**Update:**
I know well to do it trough

```
if(isset($id)){}else{
    $checkid->status();
    $title=$checkid->title;
    $content=$checkid->content);
}
```

but I was worndering if it is  possible to make it trough using

```
((isset($id)) ? '' : $checkid->status().$title=$checkid->title/*here $content break it down*//*.$content=$checkid->content*/);
```

Comment: Use an if-statement. Using the ternary operator in that place is unreadable and makes no sense to me.

Comment: If an if statement has no then clause,

Comment: if(!isset($id){ code } would make more sense than what you have in your update.  Also, you status() function needs a return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change `isset('id')` to `isset($id)`.
2. The reason why you were getting `<h1>404Not found</h1><p>Not found</p>` was because you were concatenating the value of `$content` to the value of `$title`.

Also, you're code is quite a mess. I took the liberty of cleaning it up a bit:

```
class checkid
{
    public $title;
    public $content;
    function status()
    {
        $this->title='404';
        $this->content='Not found';
    }
}
$checkid=new checkid($url);
//$id=0;
if(!isset($id))
{
    $checkid->status();
    $title=$checkid->title;
    $content=$checkid->content;
}
echo "<h1>$title</h1><p>$content</p>";
```

Comment: I know well to do it on using `if($){}else{}`, but I was thinking maybe to do it trough `(($)? : ;`.

Comment: You're abusing the ternary operator and you'll do yourself and everyone else who needs to read/edit your code a favour if you use an `if` statement like I have above.

Answer (score 3):

You don't assign `$title` and  `$content`

You probably want something like this

```
   $checkid->status();
   echo "<h1>$checkid->title</h1><p>$checkid->content</p>";
```

Comment: Yes, he does. They aren't really done properly, but the assignment on the isset line should work.

Comment: @Tom
He assigns '$checkid->status().$title', not $title?

Comment: Actually, I believe that `$title=$checkid->title` should work, even when dotted together with other assignments.

Comment: @Tom but it doesn't say `$title=$checkid->title` but `$checkid->status().$title=$checkid->title`

Comment: @Tom this work, and is not the same  `$checkid->status();$title=$checkid->title;$content=$checkid->content`

Comment: @Julian I did not. Try this code in your sandbox: `echo 'test'.$str='test'; echo $str;` It works.

Comment: @Tom any reference why this works? I cannot understand why `'test'.$str='test';` is the same as `'test';$str='test';`

Comment: @Julian Same reason why `if ($variable = mysql_...(...))` (single =) works, and `$variable = $var2 = true`. After assigning it simply "returns" the assigned value. And, @your edit: They are not the same.

Comment: It'll not work on this way `((isset($id)) ? '' : $checkid->status();$title=$checkid->title;$content=$checkid->content);` and not even on this way `((isset($id)) ? '' : $checkid->status(),$title=$checkid->title,$content=$checkid->content);`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to (ab)use a conditional expression as a if statement.

```
if(!isset($id))
{

  $checkid->status();
  $title = $checkid->title;
  $content = $checkid->content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What `isset('id')` means? do you mean `isset($id)` or `isset($_GET['id'])` ?
And, btw,

```
$checkid->status().$title=$checkid->title.$content=$checkid->content);
```

is nonsens: you attach the return of status() to `$checkid` AND YOU ATTACH `$title` which is made equal to $`checkid->title` CONCATENATED to `$content,` and everythin is assigned `$checkid->content`

A bit confusing there